# Error in nls(y~ alpha/(1 + exp(x - xO)/beta), : singular gradient

Tags: r, nls

I have the following error when using nls in R. I want to fit a sigmoid function to my data. Y is from 0.01 to 1 and x is form 0.1 to -3. I am using the code as follows:

```
dummy_df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(0.1, -3, length.out = 50),
  y = seq(0.01, 1, length.out = 50)
)

  fit <- nls(y ~ alpha / (1 + exp(x - xO) / beta),data = dummy_df,
             start = list(alpha = 1.0009, beta = -10, xO = 0),
    control = nls.control(minFactor = 0.00001, maxiter = 10))
```

This results in the following error:
error in nls(y ~ alpha/(1 + exp(x - xO)/beta),  :
singular gradient

Comment: Instead of `nls` try fitting using `optim`

Comment: Your data is a straight line. Of course it isn't possible to estimate the parameters of the model because the model doesn't fit the data at all. Also, R offers a self-starting function for this model, use it. `fit <- nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, alpha, x0, beta), data = dummy_df) `

Comment: Just to clarify something: did you mean your function to be `alpha/(1+exp((x-x0)/beta))` (note extra parentheses; this makes `beta` a scale parameter)?  That would fit with @Roland's suggestion, and would resolve the comment in the answer below that says your parameters are unidentifiable ...

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems:

**1)** the parameters are not identifiable.  It is like asking to solve `a+b=1` for `a` and `b`.  You must fix one of them.

We can write the RHS as

```
alpha / (1 + exp(x - xO) / beta)
= alpha / (1 + exp(x) * exp(-x0) / beta)
```

and exp(-x0)/beta is really a single parameter, not two.  We can address this by fixing either `beta` or `x0` to an arbitrary value.  We have used the nls2 "plinear-random" algorithm which allows us to omit starting values that enter linearly, here `alpha`, and we have set `beta` to -1 to make the parameters identifiable.  With "plinear" based algorithms we specify the RHS as a matrix whose columns are the nonlinear portions whereas the linear parameters are coefficients that multiply the columns and can optionally be specified as the column names. nls2's "plinear-random" algorithm evaluates the RHS at random values within the rectangle described by `start` and gives the best of these.  We can then use that as a starting value for `nls`.

**2)** The starting values are bad.  Use nls2 as shown below to address that.

**3)** The model does not describe the data well.  A few plots should convince one of that.

Here is the code; however,  as mentioned in (3) we are not going to get good results fitting this model to this data although we can get a result without errors.

```
set.seed(123)


library(nls2)
set.seed(123)
beta <- -1

fit0 <- nls2(y ~ cbind(alpha = 1 / (1 + exp(x - x0) / beta)),
  data = dummy_df,
  start = data.frame(x0 = c(-20, 20)),
  algorithm = "plinear-random")

fit <- nls(y ~ cbind(alpha = 1 / (1 + exp((x - xO) / beta))),
  data = dummy_df, start = coef(fit0)[1], alg = "plinear")
```

### Different formula

@Ben Bolker in comments suggests that perhaps you meant the formula.
alpha/(1 + exp((x - xO)/beta)).  If that is the case it would be easier to fit if re-expressed in the equivalent more linear parameterization shown.

```
library(nls2)
set.seed(123)

fo2 <- y ~ cbind(alpha = 1/(1 + exp(xO.over.beta - one.over.beta * x)))

fit0 <- nls2(fo2, data = dummy_df,
  start = data.frame(one.over.beta = c(-5, 5), xO.over.beta = c(-5 -5)),
  algorithm = "plinear-random")

fit2 <- nls(fo2, data = dummy_df, 
  start = c(one.over.beta = coef(fit0)[[1]], xO.over.beta = coef(fit0)[[2]]),
  algorithm = "plinear")
fit2

alpha <- coef(fit2)[[3]]
beta <- 1/coef(fit2)[["one.over.beta"]]
xO <- beta * coef(fit2)[["xO.over.beta"]]
```

In that case we can get a more reasonable fit.

```
plot(y ~ x, dummy_df)
lines(fitted(fit2) ~ x, dummy_df, col = "red")
```

(continued after graph)
[image: screenshot]

With this new model @Roland suggested in comments using the self starting model [SSlogis](https://rdrr.io/r/stats/SSlogis.html) which gives the same residual sum of squares with somewhat different coefficients.

```
nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, alpha, x0, beta), data = dummy_df)
```

Also note that the [drc package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/drc/index.html) has numerous canned growth curves that it will fit without needing starting values.  For example, this uses the 5 parameter [multi2](https://rdrr.io/cran/drc/man/multi2.html) model from that package.

```
library(drc)

fm <- drm(y ~ x, data = dummy_df, fct = multi2())

summary(fm)
sum(resid(fm)^2)  # residual sum of squares
```

### Update

Numerous updates including fixing some errors and following up on comments below the question.